# Single public IP for dual WAN using VPN?

Tags: routing, wan

In my office I have a dual wan router (Linksys LRT224) combining 2 DSL connections to give me a bit more bandwidth for certain tasks.

I'm interested to know if there is anyway to combine the 2 connections to route through 1 public IP using a VPN service?

A few of my tasks at work require a static IP, so I have to force certain ports to only use one WAN (as the IP obviously switches between packets) but I'm keen to find a way to use both links.

My ISP does not do any kind of link bonding/aggregation so I thought perhaps 2xVPN links into 1 may work?

Anyone done this before?

Comment: Consumer grade hardware is off-topic here (regardless where you use it.) Since we have an answer already, we can migrate, rather than simply on-holding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that should work, as long as you specify on your VPN client to send all traffic over the tunnel. However, since you mentioned only certain applications need the static IP, you may want to do a PBR that only sends the traffic that *needs* the static IP over the tunnel, and the rest straight out the Internet, to conserve bandwidth/latency/overhead.

Comment: Cool, so any tips on how I get each tunnel to aggregate into 1 IP? By default each tunnel will get a unique IP from the VPN pool correct?

Comment: It really depends on your VPN connection. If you have, for example, a dedicated VPN server, when you connect those two WANs, all traffic coming from those WANs will be proxied by the VPN server; the very nature of it will essentially mask your IP. The main issue I can foresee, is if your upstream VPN server gives your two WANs IPs in the same subnet. If this is the case, your router will most likely complain. Unfortunately, I can't really go into specifics, since I've never used that router.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yeah thats what I thought. This rules VPN out as a solution as each connection still has a separate IP in the end.